# is there any way to avoid exception in visual basic

Tags: visual-studio

Here is my code. `listbox.selected index` will increase until it reaches the total count of `listitem`.

```
If (ListBox1.SelectedIndex <> totalcount) Then

            ListBox1.SelectedIndex += 1

        End If
```

it provides exception

Comment: It provides what exception? Is there supposed to be a loop somewhere?

Comment: The SelectedIndex property is zero based. So if you set it to totalcount you are setting it beyond its boundary. Please give some more context of what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to init the selectedIndex property of your ListBox.

Afterwards, you have to use a **`while`** structure to perform an action more than once (and to check against the upper limit):

```
'Init
ListBox1.SelectedIndex = 0
Dim totalcount = ListBox1.Items.Count

'A loop through each element
While ListBox1.SelectedIndex <> totalcount - 1
     ListBox1.SelectedIndex += 1
End While
```